# SU Meta Community Link pointing to SO Meta Community

Tags: support, hyperlinks

Since yesterday i.e October 8th, 2010, I unable to see meta site link for SU and SF.

We have meta community link in SF and SU but both points to SO meta Community.

Am I missing anything here?

**Please see screen shot**
[image]

Comment: Which "meta" link? The one at the top of the page is correct. The one in the footer points to meta.stackoverflow unless you're here on meta.superuser when it *does* point to meta.superuser.

Comment: Screenshots please. I have no idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this was changed by the team, and to be honest makes sense since there is already a meta link to the SE meta in the top link list. I personally have found it irritating that there is no way to get to MSO from the site.

I can't seem to find any official confirmation of this anywhere on MSO itself, however I am not convinced it is a bug.